# ios 12.0 how can I delete specific plug in applications within the Message app?

Tags: messages, ios

I don't want Message apps except for photos to show up in the bottom when I'm composing a message.

How can I delete them from Message so I can't tap them accidentally or see them?

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out - in imessage conversation area, scroll the line of apps to the left, select the three dots, scroll thru both favorite and all apps, swipe left on each unwanted app. As usual in ios, a 'small swipe' left shows a 'delete' selection, a 'big swipe' just deletes it. Be sure to select 'done' to save all your changes